# Load external js file with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Looked for it everywhere, and found the answer but lost. anyone knows how to load an external .js file from another js file?

```
main_lobj1.onreadystatechange = function(){     
  if (main_lobj1.readyState == 4) {if (main_lobj1.status == 200) { 
    document.getElementById("middleDiv_m").innerHTML=main_lobj1.responseText;  
  jQuery.getScript('jquery/tabs.js')        
  }
}
```

innerHTML works and responce text is pasted. The problem is that JS is not working in that document. jQuery.getScript should be loading that external js file, but it doesnt

Comment: the datatype you are receiving in this context is text but you are asking for Script,,, so you  need to return script,, so the datatype is script

Comment: @SamArulRaj, `geScript` already parses the return as script, there is no need to tell `getScript` to parse as script. Plus he is requesting a .js file so I don't get what you are saying.

Comment: @Semur, are you using the correct path in getScript function? And also make sure you have loaded the jquery file. Check you browser console(chrome or firefox) to see if it throws an error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**This is the way you can do it to load an external js file to Jquery**

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "test.js",
  dataType: "script"
});
```

Comment: This is simply copying out exactly what the jQuery manual says is shorthand for `getScript`. If his current method doesn't work, this probably won't either. I suspect the problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 11):

Exactly for this reason a function [$.getScript()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) exist in jquery. You can use it simply in this way:

```
$.getScript("test.js", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
  // this is your callback.
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you call an external script you want to base your script on you may want to take note that ajax-based jquery script are asynchronous by defealt.

Calling an external script asynchronousily will cause the rest of the rest being executed before the external script is loaded.

Today I ran into the same problem which was easily being solved by making a small adition to Sam Arul Raj's post:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "test.js",
  dataType: "script",
  async: false
});
```